# Rectangular boxes in a rotational view with an arrow using beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I would like to construct four rectangular boxes with arrows using beamer, which looks like the following figure.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I have tried the following, but I couldn't manage to place texts above and beside the arrows. I was wondering if someone could help me. Thank you in advance.

```
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \begin{frame}
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.6}[0.6]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, place/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,rounded corners,fill=blue!25,},trans/.style={align=center},auto,scale=7]    
         \node[place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a1) {1\textsuperscript{st} TEXT};
         \node[right=1cm of a1,place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a2) {2\textsuperscript{nd} TEXT};
         \node[below=1cm of a2,place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a3) {3\textsuperscript{rd} TEXT};
         \node[left=1cm of a3,place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a4) {4\textsuperscript{th} TEXT};  
            \draw [->] (a1) -- (a2);
            \draw [->] (a2) -- (a3);
            \draw [->] (a3) -- (a4);       
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `node[midway] {f}` to your arrows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    

    \begin{frame}
    \centering
    \scalebox{0.6}[0.6]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, place/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,rounded corners,fill=blue!25,},trans/.style={align=center},auto,scale=7]    
         \node[place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a1) {1\textsuperscript{st} TEXT};
         \node[right=1cm of a1,place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a2) {2\textsuperscript{nd} TEXT};
         \node[below=1cm of a2,place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a3) {3\textsuperscript{rd} TEXT};
         \node[left=1cm of a3,place,fill=green!25,inner sep=8, font=\Large ] (a4) {4\textsuperscript{th} TEXT};  
            \draw [->] (a1) -- (a2) node[midway] {f};
            \draw [->] (a2) -- (a3) node[midway] {f};
            \draw [->] (a3) -- (a4) node[midway,above] {f};       
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]